# What is the difference between [pwsh] and [Powershell Integrated Console] on VS Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

What is the difference between [pwsh] and [Powershell Integreted Console] on VS Code?
I usualy use pwsh.
Today, when I installed the powershell extension and then tried to update the powershell, the Powershell Integreted Console started up and found out. What is this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- `pwsh[.exe]` is the *executable file name* of *PowerShell [Core]* (v6+), the cross-platform edition of PowerShell built on .NET Core / .NET 5+; by contrast, `powershell.exe` is the executable name of the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition (v5.1-), built on the Windows-only .NET Framework (v4.8-)

  - Windows PowerShell comes with Windows itself, whereas PowerShell [Core] must be [installed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell) on demand (on all supported platforms).<sup>[+]</sup>
- VSCode ([Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)) has an ***integrated terminal*** (console) that **can run *any* shell**, such as `cmd.exe`, `bash`, or `pwsh` or `powershell`.

  - Shells that run in the integrated terminal by default have no special integration with the files being edited. They *show by their executable file name* in the dropdown list in the integrated terminal's toolbar; e.g.:
    [image]
- By contrast, the ***PowerShell Integrated Console* is a *special* shell** that **comes with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)** and offers *integration with PowerShell code being edited*, notably to provide *linting and debugging support*, among other features.

  - The PowerShell Integrated Console starts on demand when you first open/activate an editor with PowerShell code in a session, and it shows as follows in the integrated terminal's toolbar: [image]
  - You can [use the PowerShell extension's configuration to *choose*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/using-vscode#choosing-a-version-of-powershell-to-use-with-the-extension) the specific PowerShell executable to use, which on Windows allows you to choose between running PowerShell [Core] (`pwsh.exe`) and Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) in the PowerShell Integrated Console.

    - If a PowerShell [Core] version is installed and it is installed in a well-known location<sup>[*]</sup>, it will be used by default; the fallback on
      Windows is Windows PowerShell. Since PowerShell [Core] versions can be installed side by side, you can switch between different versions, if installed.
    - If a PowerShell [Core] version in installed in a nonstandard location and is therefore not discovered automatically, you can tell the PowerShell extension where to find it, either via the Settings GUI or via `settings.json`, as shown in the linked topic and the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375).
    - Whenever the active tab is a PowerShell source-code file, the status bar in the bottom-right corner shows the PowerShell version that is being used if you however over or **click on the `{}` icon**; versions >= 6 imply PowerShell [Core].
      *If configured*, there's a separate icon that directly invokes the PowerShell session menu when clicked and which reflects the active version *number* - again, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60555493/45375); e.g.: [image]

---

<sup>[+] as of v7.0; time will tell if PowerShell [Core] will ship with future versions of Windows, and perhaps even other platforms.</sup>

<sup>[*] From the [linked docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/using-vscode#choosing-a-version-of-powershell-to-use-with-the-extension): "This feature looks at a few well-known paths on different operating systems to discover install locations of PowerShell. If you installed PowerShell to a non-typical location, it might not show up initially in the Session Menu. You can extend the session menu by [adding your own custom paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/using-vscode#adding-your-own-powershell-paths-to-the-session-menu)." If you use one of the [official installers](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell), the PowerShell extension should find your installation.</sup>