# VSCode overrides PowerShell ExecutionPolicy

Tags: powershell, registry, visual-studio-code

When using `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` within VSCode for PowerShell v5 x64 & x86 it returns the following:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process          Bypass
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

When using the same command within VSCode and using a PowerShell v7 console it returns:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    RemoteSigned
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

There are 2 registry entries that set the ExecutionPolicy (Originally: ByPass)

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command      REG_SZ  "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process RemoteSigned }; & '%1'" 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command        REG_SZ  "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process RemoteSigned }; & '%1'"
```

These 2 entries were originally set to Set the Execution Policy to ByPass , and I have set these 2 entries manually to RemoteSigned. (why are these 2 entries within the registry and why were they set to bypass?!).

There are no further Policies set for PowerShell within the registry then these 2 entries.
Setting these to RemoteSigned seemed to have done the trick for v7 but not for v5.

When checking the ExecutionPolicy within a v5 PowerShell Console they are all undefined.

when checking the vscode-powershell.log it says that it starts PowerShell with arguments: 
`PowerShell args: -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module ...`

I can see the vscode powershell extension sets some of these parameters within the following file:
*C:\Users\UserName.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.3.0\out\src\process.js*
But I am not sure if this is the correct file to make these changes.

I want to be able to check/set the ExecutionPolicy for VSCode to RemoteSigned when it starts the language server , where do I do this?

Also , Why are there 2 entries within the registry that sets the ExecutionPolicy to ByPass when the ExecutionPolicy Not Equals AllSigned. This might have occurred after having installed Chocolatey using their one line installer: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

Im not using any profiles.

I know its a bit messy, sorry for that , my main question is where VSCode sets the ExecutionPolicy when starting the language server and can I change this.
When doing some investigation, I figured there was 2 registry entries that sets the ExecutionPolicy to bypass , why is that , is that standard , looks like a security issue. (which might have caused by installing chocolatey, not sure)

Comment: Figured that the 2 registry entries that set the ExecutionPolicy are not pointing toward any shell that can be started normally. They do not influence the ExecutionPolicy within a console shell when starting any of them. Not v5 console and ISE , nor v7 , nor x86 or x64 … What shell are they pointing to and why are these entries there ?

Comment: Setting the execution policy for the process does not help since restarting VSCode will set it back to bypass. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Force -Verbose`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio code cmd error: Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199111/visual-studio-code-cmd-error-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) respects the persistent execution policy settings<sup>[1]</sup> of whatever PowerShell version / edition it is configured to use (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132705/45375)); to manage these settings, use [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) from the respective version / edition.

- For instance, to persistently set the policy for the current user to `RemoteSigned`, run
  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

If you want to *override* the persistently configured policy in Visual Studio Code, add a `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command to the `$PROFILE` file *as used by the PowerShell extension*:

- From the PowerShell Integrated Console, execute `psedit $PROFILE` to open the file for editing.
- Add `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process RemoteSigned` to the file.

---

As for **your question**:

Since `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a composite view of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`, there is only *one* entry in this case, which you can access with either key path.

This entry, however, does *not* control the persistent execution policies for Windows PowerShell; instead, it is a convenience *context-menu* command definition that allows you to execute a `*.ps1` file directly from File Explorer or the desktop. As a security feature, the command ensures that the execution policy in effect *for the process being created only* (`-Scope Process`) is at least as restrictive as `RemoteSigned`.

---

[1] **Optional reading: Where PowerShell editions store their (non-GPO) persistent execution-policy settings**:

<sup>The following applies to *Windows only*, because execution policies are fundamentally unsupported on Unix-like platforms.</sup>

Note:

- As shown in you question, execute `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` lists all the policies in effect across scopes:

  - Settings in more specific scopes - if defined - take precedence; that is, the most specific scope that doesn't state `Undefined` is the one in effect for the process at hand.
  - **Group policies** ([GPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy)-based settings) - i.e., scopes `UserPolicy` and `MachinePolicy`, which cannot be set with `Set-ExecutionPolicy` - **can *override*** the `CurrentUser`, `LocalMachine`, and `Process` scopes; notably, this means that even ad-hoc attempts to override the execution policy via `-Scope Process Bypass` / the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) parameter may be prevented.
- You should use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to change the persistent settings rather than modifying these locations directly.

**PowerShell [Core]** (version 6 or higher) stores the settings in **`.json` files**:

- **Current-user policy** (`Scope -CurrentUser`; file may not exist):

  - `"$([Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments'))/powershell/powershell.config.json"`
- **Machine policy** (`Scope -LocalMachine`):

  - `"$PSHOME\powershell.config.json"`
  - Note that the filename root is `powershell`, even though the actual executable filename root is `pwsh`:

**Windows PowerShell** (version up to 5.1) stores the settings in the **registry** (keys won't exist, if you've never run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` or if you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to set a scope's policy to `Undefined`):

- **Current-user policy** (`-Scope CurrentUser`): `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`, value `ExecutionPolicy`

  - Both the 32-bit and the 64-bit PowerShell executables see the same value, because there are no bit-ness-specific hives for `HKCU` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USERS`).
- **Machine policy** (`-Scope LocalMachine`): `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell`, value `ExecutionPolicy`

  - **Caveat**: The 32-bit and the 64-bit executables see distinct values, because 32-bit applications have a separate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` hive.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this can be of any help for further users with this issue, but reading from the VSCode docs the recommended way is to add a new profile for Powershell inside `settings.json`, without needing to change the current policy globally or using an extension. Something along these lines:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
     "PowerShell": {
         "source": "PowerShell",
         "args": [
             "-ExecutionPolicy",
             "Bypass"
         ]
     }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

Comment: I also added the following args to make it print a visible warning when it's disabled:

    "-noexit",
    "-Command",
    "Write-Warning \"ExecutionPolicy is disabled\""