# Setting Powershell version used in the PowerShell host?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am using the .NET PowerShell host. I have version 5 and 7 installed of PowerShell. When running:

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

- it returns:

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      18362  1110

How do I make it run version 7 of PowerShell?

Comment: "I am using the .NET PowerShell host", I assume this means compiling against _.NET Framework_? PowerShell 7 runs on .NET Core >3.1, so you won't be able to use it from a .NET Framework host.

Comment: Yes, correct. Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft's documentation, you should be able to load a previous version of PowerShell.

Separate installation path and executable name

PowerShell 7 installs to a new directory, enabling side-by-side execution with Windows PowerShell 5.1.

Install locations by version:
Windows PowerShell 5.1: `$env:WINDIR\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
PowerShell Core 6.x: `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\6`
PowerShell 7: `$env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\7`

The new location is added to your `PATH` allowing you to run both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7. If you're migrating from PowerShell Core 6.x to PowerShell 7, PowerShell 6 is removed and the `PATH` replaced.

In Windows PowerShell, the PowerShell executable is named `powershell.exe`. In version 6 and above, the executable is named `pwsh.exe`. The new name makes it easy to support side-by-side execution of both versions.

Have a read of the webpage, using the link provided.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/migrating-from-windows-powershell-51-to-powershell-7?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1):

Powershell (Core) 7 is a [different executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132705/2060966): `pwsh.exe`

```
powershell => Windows PowerShell (latest: v5.1)
pwsh => PowerShell Core (latest: v7)
```

Answer (score 1):

From a console just do

```
where powershell.exe

-and-

where pwsh.exe
```

you should obtain:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

-and-

C:\APL\Microsoft\PowerShell64\pwsh.exe
```

then you can call the .exe(s) direcly...
to bypass any issues with .cmd(s)/.bat(s)/.lnk(s)/alias/hijackers/etc. etc.