# Re enable Import Module Psreadline warning

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, warnings, screen-readers

This warning keeps popping in the terminal of Visual Code app

```
Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has
         disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes.
         If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.
```

Even if I change the value to `0` via regedit, the warning still shows.

Comment: Did you reboot having set the registry value to 0?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The implications of your symptom are:

- **Windows is in screen-reader mode** (a Windows accessibility feature for the visually impaired) at the time your PowerShell session starts.
- **You're using a *regular* PowerShell session**, either in a console window / in Windows Terminal or in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.

  - By contrast, if you use Visual Studio Code *with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)*, which enables a much richer PowerShell code-authoring experience, the problem doesn't occur, because the sessions provided by the extension in the so-called [*PowerShell Integrated Console*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132705/45375) do *not* perform this check (as of version `2021.2.2`), and therefore *do* load [`PSReadLine`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine) (the module providing a rich command-line editing experience) and do not emit a warning. It is unclear if this unconditional override is by design or an oversight.
  - While you *could* follow the advice in the error message and add
    `Import-Module PSReadLine` to your `$PROFILE` file and doing so will re-enable PSReadLine for a rich command-line editing experience, but *you'll still see the warning* on startup, because it is emitted by PowerShell *before* the `$PROFILE` file is loaded. That said, if screen-reader mode is enabled *by design* on your system, this is the right solution.

---

**If this mode is (accidentally) turned on *persistently*, via the *registry***, you can turn it off as follows:

```bash
Set-ItemProperty 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access' On 0
```

**Note**:

- This change **requires a logoff or reboot** to take effect.
- To *query* the persistent mode, use:

```bash
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access' On
```

---

**If this mode has accidentally been turned on *in-OS-session***, by an application that is either ill-behaved in that it doesn't turn the mode back off again or has crashed before being able to do so, you **can turn the mode off *ad hoc*** so that ***future* PowerShell sessions in the same OS user session no longer see the warning**:

The following, gratefully adapted from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11751#issuecomment-600120959), is a PowerShell command that does this via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) and ad hoc-compiled C# code (which is necessary to perform P/Invoke calls):

```bash
# Run in PowerShell
(Add-Type -PassThru -Name ScreenReaderUtil -Namespace WinApiHelper -MemberDefinition @'
  const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x0002;
  const int SPI_SETSCREENREADER = 0x0047;

  [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);

  public static void EnableScreenReader(bool enable)
  {
    var ok = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENREADER, enable ? 1u : 0u, IntPtr.Zero, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    if (!ok)
    {
      throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
  }
'@)::EnableScreenReader($false)
```

Comment: The registry trick worked for me.

Comment: *if its answered very well/and its about powershell/thats mklement0* (sung to the tune of 'Thats Amore')

Comment: I just installed the extention, but i dont see any effect, still getting this message. Also Im wondering this message started to occure when I started to use screen reader, but I didnt change anything in the settings of windows, was it changed by sr?

Comment: @daza, I have no explanation for your symptom, and on my Windows 11 machine the registry setting doesn't seem to change anymore when you turn on screen reader, and I don't even get the warning anymore.

Comment: @daza, when I manually set the registry setting to `1` in Windows 11  - which does _not_ correspond to turning on the screen reader - I still see the behavior described in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this(just woked for me)

Step 1: Open **"RUN"** (WIN + R)

Step 2: Type "**regedit**"

Step 3: On the left side, there is a folder named **"HKEY_CURRENT_USER"**; click on it.

Step 4: Click the sub-folder named **"Control Panel"** and then click the sub-folder named **"Blind access"** or follow this path **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access**

Step 5: Right Click on the option **"On"**, chose the option **"Modify"** and then set the value 0.

Now **Restart** your computer, and PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

If NVDA is installed, open the NVDA first. Then right click on NVDA icon on the Windows taskbar "Notification Area" and **reset configuration to factory defaults**. Then restart your VSCode.

[image]